# Identify a unique String

Tags: java, string

I have some strings read in from a file that look like this

```
"Anderson, T",CWS,SS,...
"Anderson, B",MIA,3B,...
"Galvis, F",CIN,SS,...
```

I need the user to input a name (such as "Anderson" or "Galvis") and if the name is insufficient to identify a unique player I need to print an error message.
So if the user wants to pick "Anderson, T" they would have to specify "Anderson, T").

Currently I have a function that takes in the name ("Anderson, T" or "Anderson, B") and it finds the correct string, the function can be found below

```
public static boolean findPlayer(String playerName) {
    // Find specified player
    int found = -1;
    for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
        if (players.get(j).toString().toLowerCase().contains(playerName.toLowerCase())) {
            found = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Is there a way for me to modify the code so that it takes in "Anderson" and then print out an error?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Honestly, ive been having trouble wrapping my head around this. But i will continue researching it and update my post

Comment: replace `contains` with `equals` and search will be exact.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to check whether the user has input enough of a substring to uniquely match on of the strings in your list? As in "Anderson" should fail, because there are two "Anderson"s, but "Gal" should match with "Galvis, F" because there are no other names that "Gal" could be a match for? Just trying to understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Now read: [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: Thanks for that!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the method is named `findPlayer`, it should return the found player.

Since you want it to fail if there are multiple player matching the name, you could use an exception to indicate that.

You obviously want to know if no player is found, so you can return `null`, or change return type to `Optional`, or throw another exception to indicate that.

Here we'll go with exception for non-unique name, and `null` for not found:

```
public static Player findPlayer(String playerName) {
    Pattern nameRegex = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(playerName), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Player foundPlayer = null;
    for (Player player : players) {
        if (nameRegex.matcher(player.toString()).find()) {
            if (foundPlayer != null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Multiple player matches name: " + playerName);
            foundPlayer = player;
        }
    }
    return foundPlayer; // returns null if not found
}
```

Changed code to use regex for case-insensitive `contains` logic, so it doesn't create a lot of intermediate lower-case strings during the search.